# How can I implement this kind of resolution grey boxes?

Tags: boxes

I wanna make a kind of a question/answer thing, so I wanna split the answer from the question by "boxing" my resolution with a kind of a grey box like that in the picture below. The image is just an example, I don´t wanna write that on my document, so, I would be very pleased if you only teach me how can I make the grey box.

[image]

Comment: This link can you help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472008/spacing-error-with-mdframed-over-page-break or this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204616/how-to-create-framed-text-with-background-color

Comment: Yes, I managed to do it, thank you very much for you help !